# A reference book to study Thom-Pontryagin Theory from basic

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am a beginner in Algebraic Topology and Differential Topology. Please suggest me a reference book to study Thom-Pontryagin Theory from basic and which book is easy to understand for a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~hrm/papers/cobordism.pdf Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: You might look at section 7 of Milnor's beautiful little book *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint*.

Answer (score 0):

The standard reference for this would be Robert Stong's book "Notes on Cobordism Theory". The first chapter sets up the theory of cobordism categories, and then in the second chapter, the Pontryagin-Thom Theorem is proved in the generality of cobordism classes of manifolds with normal/tangential structure. I think this book is not too difficult to understand. Nonetheless, the first chapter requires some basic category theory.